# how can edit/remove markers from google map in html

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

i have a html page that displays address points into google map.
my geo points will refresh each 20 seconds and i want to remove old locations and mark new geo locations :
my html and java script code is :

```
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
  var markers = [];
  var locations = [
    ['<h4>Bondi Beach</h4>', -33.890542, 151.274856],
    ['<h4>Coogee Beach</h4>', -33.923036, 151.259052],
    ['<h4>Cronulla Beach</h4>', -34.028249, 151.157507],
    ['<h4>Manly Beach</h4>', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
    ['<h4>Maroubra Beach</h4>', -33.950198, 151.259302]
  ];
  var iconURLPrefix = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';
  var icons = [
    iconURLPrefix + 'red-dot.png',
    iconURLPrefix + 'green-dot.png',
    iconURLPrefix + 'blue-dot.png',
    iconURLPrefix + 'orange-dot.png',
    iconURLPrefix + 'purple-dot.png',
    iconURLPrefix + 'pink-dot.png',
    iconURLPrefix + 'yellow-dot.png'
  ]
  var iconsLength = icons.length;

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      panControl: false,
      zoomControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
      }
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      maxWidth: 160
  });
  var iconCounter = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          map: map,
          icon: icons[iconCounter]
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
          return function () {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
      })(marker, i));

      iconCounter++;
      if (iconCounter >= iconsLength) {
          iconCounter = 0;
      }
  }

  function autoCenter() {
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          bounds.extend(markers[i].position);
      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
  autoCenter();
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  setInterval(function () {
      markers = null;
      locations = [
        ['<h4>Bondi Beach</h4>', -34.890542, 151.274856],
        ['<h4>Coogee Beach</h4>', -33.923036, 151.259052],
        ['<h4>Cronulla Beach</h4>', -34.028249, 151.157507],
        ['<h4>Manly Beach</h4>', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
        ['<h4>Maroubra Beach</h4>', -33.950198, 151.259302]
      ];
      icons = [
        iconURLPrefix + 'red-dot.png',
        iconURLPrefix + 'green-dot.png',
        iconURLPrefix + 'blue-dot.png',
        iconURLPrefix + 'orange-dot.png',
        iconURLPrefix + 'purple-dot.png',
        iconURLPrefix + 'pink-dot.png',
        iconURLPrefix + 'yellow-dot.png'
      ];
      iconsLength = icons.length;

      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
      for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
              map: map,
              icon: icons[iconCounter]
          });
          markers.push(marker);
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
              return function () {
                  infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
              }
          })(marker, i));
          iconCounter++;
          if (iconCounter >= iconsLength) {
              iconCounter = 0;
          }
      }
  }, 20000);
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are running into

Comment: i want when setTimeOut be run first clear all markers (points) and display new locations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a javascript error with your code `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null`.  You are setting the markers array to `null`, after that you can't push the new markers on it.

Fix that problem.  To remove the markers, iterate through that array calling .setMap(null) on each marker to remove it from the map, then set the array to empty (`markers = [];`).

```
  for (var i=0; i<markers.length;i++) {
      markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4pd7fttp/)

code snippet:

```js
var markers = [];
var map;
var locations = [
  ['<h4>Bondi Beach</h4>', -33.890542, 151.274856],
  ['<h4>Coogee Beach</h4>', -33.923036, 151.259052],
  ['<h4>Cronulla Beach</h4>', -34.028249, 151.157507],
  ['<h4>Manly Beach</h4>', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
  ['<h4>Maroubra Beach</h4>', -33.950198, 151.259302]
];
var iconURLPrefix = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';
var icons = [
  iconURLPrefix + 'red-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'green-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'blue-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'orange-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'purple-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'pink-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'yellow-dot.png'
]
var iconsLength = icons.length;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.92, 151.25),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
    }
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    maxWidth: 160
  });
  var iconCounter = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      title: "orig",
      icon: icons[iconCounter]
    });

    markers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));

    iconCounter++;
    if (iconCounter >= iconsLength) {
      iconCounter = 0;
    }
  }
  autoCenter();
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  setInterval(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers = [];
    locations = [
      ['<h4>Bondi Beach</h4>', -34.890542, 151.274856],
      ['<h4>Coogee Beach</h4>', -33.923036, 151.259052],
      ['<h4>Cronulla Beach</h4>', -34.028249, 151.157507],
      ['<h4>Manly Beach</h4>', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
      ['<h4>Maroubra Beach</h4>', -33.950198, 151.259302]
    ];
    icons = [
      iconURLPrefix + 'red-dot.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'green-dot.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'blue-dot.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'orange-dot.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'purple-dot.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'pink-dot.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'yellow-dot.png'
    ];
    iconsLength = icons.length;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: icons[iconCounter]
      });
      markers.push(marker);
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
      iconCounter++;
      if (iconCounter >= iconsLength) {
        iconCounter = 0;
      }
    }
  }, 20000);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function autoCenter() {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(markers[i].position);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```